# Converting Pdf file to images with Imagick and PHP

Tags: php, imagick

Program to  load  pdf image and at the same time convert them to jpg using Imagick.But couldnt convert and load it in Destination directory.

```
                    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                    $fileName = substr($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 5).".".$ext;
                    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
                    $fileDate = date('d.m.Y');
                    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
                    $folder = $_POST['folder'];


                    $uploadfile1="$media_dir/$fileName";

                    $imagick = new imagick();
                    $imagick->readImage($uploadfile1);//line 149
                    $imagick->setImageFormat('jpg');
                    foreach($imagick as $i=>$imagick) 
                    { 


                    $imagick->writeImage($uploadfile1. " page ". ($i+1) ." of ".  $pages.".jpg"); 
}
```

Error

> Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: unable to open image
>   `/opt/ama/mediaFiles/phpe765pr.pdf': No such file or directory @
>   error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701 in
>   /home/james/workspace/ama/1.1/userinterface/webfleet/gui/ama/modules/mediaFiles/uploadFile.php:149Stack
>   trace:#0
>   /home/james/workspace/ama/1.1/userinterface/webfleet/gui/ama/modules/mediaFiles/uploadFile.php(149):
>   Imagick->readimage('/opt/gpssi/medi...')#1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/james/workspace/ama/1.1/userinterface/webfleet/gui/gpssi/modules/mediaFiles/uploadFile.php on line 149

Comment: The error says `No such file or directory` so what is the question? The filepath is wrong thats why you can''t read the file

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the path of

> /opt/ama/mediaFiles/phpe765pr.pdf

Make sure the path exists and the necessary privileges are given to all the folders in the path along the file to read it.